# Criando uma tabela repetitiva no ionic

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic, typescript

Vamos ao problema:

Preciso criar uma tabela pelo ionic que, assim como no álbum do instagram, fica dividido em 3 imagens por linha,esse código foi feito pelo angular. Aqui está meu código HTML no ionic:

```
<ion-content> 
    <h1>Fotos</h1>
  <ion-list> 
    <ion-grid> 

      <ion-item *ngFor="let photo of photos">
          <ion-list id="album">
            <div class="foto"><img src="{{photo.url}}"></div>
          </ion-list>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-grid>

 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Parte .TS

```
interface IPhoto {
  albumId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  url: boolean;
  thumbnilUrl: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage {

  api: string;
  photos: IPhoto[];

  constructor(
  public httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.api = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

    // Obtenção das fotos da API
    httpClient.get(this.api + '/photos')
      .subscribe((res: IPhoto[]) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.photos = res;
      });
  }}
```

Meu professor tem a mania de ensinar linguagens que nem ele sabe, e como é o trabalho final, ele não vai me ajudar.

 O que eu preciso é de uma forma de transformar esses posts em uma table. Pelo PHP, JavaScript ou C# eu até saberia fazer, mas eu não sei como eu poderia fazer um `if` dentro do TypeScript para que ele finalizasse uma linha e criasse outra.

Eu pensei em criar uma `div` no CSS, que criasse uma tabela de tamanho específico que limitasse as fotos, mas não sei se isso funcionaria. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Cara vc pode fazer um ngFor num td dentro de uma tabela e dependo se o indice for multiplo de 3 vc cria uma linha nova

Comment: como isso poderia ser feito pelo ngFor @EduardoVargas? Esse comando faz mais do que repetição?

Comment: o ngFor vc usa pra criar os tds e rastrear o indice ai vc precisa de um ngif pra saber se cria uma linha nova ou não

Comment: Então se eu criar um: `<ion-row class='row' *ngIf="ion-col<2 then crianova else termina">` e  fizer os templates: `<ng-template #crianova></ion-row><ion-row></ng-template> <ng-template #termina></ion-row></ng-template>` ele iria ler?

Answer (score -1):

No ionic quando utilizado o ion-col, tem a propriedade "size" que funciona na mesma forma das colunas do bootstrap.

```html
<ion-col size="2">
          <ion-text>DP</ion-text>
        </ion-col>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).